# Counting characters of each word in a string with Sed

Tags: unix, sed

So my question is how do you count individual characters of each word in a given string in Linux?

Here is an illustration of what I want to achieve:

```
$ echo "But a time I spent wandering in bloomy night;" | ...
```

should give me:

```
314159265
```

3 for the characters in the word 'But', 1 for 'a' and so on..

Comment: +1 for using `sed` instead of `wc`: I know it's a ridiculous use-case, as in why bother when we have `wc`, but I think that it's fun to find unusual stuff like this that `sed` can do, even if `sed` can't actually do what's being asked right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you specified `sed`; counting things is not its forte.  This is easy enough with `awk`, though:

```
$ echo "But a time I spent wandering in bloomy night" |
  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%d", length($i); print ""}' 
314159265
```

Note that the semicolon in your version would be counted, meaning it would incorrectly give the last digit as 6 instead of 5. If you want to count only letters, you can introduce `sed` back into the mix:

```
$ echo "But a time I spent wandering in bloomy night;" |
  sed 's/[^a-zA-Z ]//g' |
  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%d", length($i); print ""}'
```

Alternatively, you could do it all with shell built-ins.  Assuming your shell is bash, this will work:

```
echo "But a time I spent wandering in bloomy night;" | {
read -a pi   
for d in "${pi[@]}"; do
  d=${d//[^A-Za-z]}
  echo -n ${#d}
done
echo; }
```

Going the other way from AWK, it's a one-liner in Perl or Ruby:

```
$ echo "But a time I spent wandering in bloomy night;" |
  perl -lne 'print map { s/[^A-Za-z]//g; length } split' 

$ echo "But a time I spent wandering in bloomy night;" |
  ruby -ne 'puts $_.split.map{|w| w.gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/, "").length }.join'
```

Comment: Yeah i want it to only count letters and like delete symbols other than letters

Comment: But still i'm wondering if you can do it with sed, i know awk is the the proper command to do it but we haven't really seen it yet

Comment: I don't know of a way to get the length of a bit of text using `sed`.  Which is not to say there might not be one..

Comment: @Karatawi the proper command for counting anything is actually `wc` (word count), but keep in mind that when you tell it to count characters/bytes it will include an extra byte/char for the `NULL` terminator at the end of the string.  EDIT: or it could possibly be a `\n` (newline) instead of `\0` (`NULL`), not sure.

Comment: Nothing counts the NULs; it's the newline.  `printf  hello | wc -c` outputs 5; `echo hello | wc -c` (or `printf '%s\n' hello | wc -c`)  outputs 6.